# og:url does not represent the input URL. You can safely ignore this message after double checking the provided value

Tags: facebook, url, warnings, facebook-opengraph

Why would [Facebook Sharing Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/) tool warn me with this prompt?

I do not understand the warning.

> ### Warnings That Should Be Fixed
>
> The provided value for 'og:url' might be incorrect.
>
> The provided property 'og:url' ('URL-link') does not represent the input URL. You can safely ignore this message after double checking the provided value.

Screenshot of warning:

[image: Warnings That Should Be Fixed]

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask questions about your website there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why would Facebook's tool caution me, if it can be safely ignored?

It can be safely ignored **if you manually check that the URLs match.** That means the software made a mistake. You cannot ignore it without doing that check.

Consider it like an antivirus. Most antivirus programs trap many legitimate things as well. You can safely open the files tagged by an antivirus if you verify that they are from a legitimate publisher or trusted source.